# How to connect android phone client to python server on same network using socket programming?

Tags: python, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to connect my android app (client) to my PC (python server). They are both on the same network. I can ping my android phone from my PC and PC from phone. But when I try to connect them using sockets android app gets stuck at connecting and after a while throws a timeout exception.
Here is the code of Android Client class:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private String mCommand;
private String mHostIP;

public Client(String mCommand, String mHostIP) {
    this.mCommand = mCommand;
    this.mHostIP = mHostIP;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(mHostIP);
        Socket soc = new Socket(serverAddr,9999);

        OutputStream toServer = soc.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(toServer);
        output.println(mCommand);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(toServer);
        out.writeBytes(mCommand);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

It gets stuck at new Socket and throws exception after a while.

Here is the code for Python server:

```
import socket
import os

hostname = socket.gethostname()
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print('My IP: '+IPAddr)
port  = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("socket successfully created")

server_address = ('192.168.10.4', 9999)

s.bind(server_address)

s.listen(1)
print ("socket is listening")

while True:
    try:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ('Got connection from', addr)
        type = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print(type)
    finally:
        print('Could not connect')
        c.close()
        break
```

Comment: What is the ip the client is using? Which exception is thrown?

Comment: Show how you start your async task.

Comment: `print('My IP: '+IPAddr)`. Well.. what is printed?

Comment: `'192.168.10.4',` Why hard coding that address,? Is it different from that what is printed? Why would you bind your server to an/that address?

Comment: The client waits and then throws a SocketTimeOutException.

Comment: I start the task my creating a new object of client class.

Comment: print('My IP: ' + IPAddr) prints the address of the host which I can enter in the client. And when I was testing the code 192.168.10.4 was the host IP.

Comment: Please guide me what am I doing wrong and why am I unable to connect to the host.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know what goes wrong. Is there s firewall?

Comment: Yes, It was a firewall. I turned off Windows Defender and run the code again and this time phone was able to made the connect. Thank you for the help, if you can answer to the post rather than comment I will mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a close look at your firewall.